# Denwer корневой путь

Tags: denwer

При написании абсолютного пути, обозреватель принимает корневой путь в качестве `loalhost`, а не папки сайта. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сайты в денвере по умолчанию открываются на поддоменах. Т.е. для `site.ru` путь будет:

> http://site.ru.localhost/

И путь:

> /home/localhost/site.ru

Не думаю, что вам стоит это менять. Если не открывается, перезапустите (ярлык `Restart Denwer`).

Comment: Не знаю, я всю жизнь запускал как домены второго уровня. О_о
там же, где test1.ru надо создавать свои сайты. И будет все окей.

Comment: так можно и `http://ololo/` сделать, не знаю, я так пробовал, но: на хостинге папки вида site.ru, качал я их так же и, соответственно, для просмотра изменений слишком много приходилось делать.

Answer (score 0):

Положить сайт в "правильное место". Если не ошибаюсь `локалхост/хоум/ввв/имя_сайта` и тогда он будет работать как надо.

Comment: не угадал. ^^ `\папка_установки_денвера_по_умолчанию_WebServers\home\имя_сайта\ввв\`